# Exception in running word count example in Hadoop on multi node cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i follow the tutorial whose link is [here](http://jinutechworld.blogspot.in/2012/02/multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu.html)

i configured all the steps correctly. but in the step 8 that is Example MapReduce job using word count
it throws exception when i execute command

```
./bin/hadoop jar /home/ila/hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-out
```

How can i solve this problem. Exception is as follows:-

```
  hduser@ila:/usr/local/hadoop-0.22.0/bin$ ./hadoop jar /home/ila/hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-out
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /home/ila/hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:130)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:133)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:128)
```

thanks in advance... [:)] [:)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the jar file being referred in the command (`/home/ila/hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar`) in NOT present. Its clear that you are using `hadoop-0.22.0` and that wont have `hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar` shipped along with it.

Try to find the `hadoop-*-examples jar` in the hadoop installation directory and use that in the command. That should solve the issue. Typically it will be named as `hadoop-0.22.0-examples.jar` as the jar naming is related to the hadoop version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that there isn't a `hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar` file in your home directory (`/home/ila`)?

Maybe amend as follows (based upon your relative path to the hadoop command):

```
./bin/hadoop hadoop-0.20.1-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-out
```

Although i see from the link you provided, you are prompted to download the examples jar - where did you download this file too? This should be the path you provide